# How to add keydown/up event listener on eclipse rcp editor view?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

So I basically need to get key press up/down event from eclipse editor view. I googled it for couple hours but only found keypress events from shell ([like in here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Geteventtype.htm)). But this method do not work in/from editor view.
So maybe some one knows how to add keypress event listener in editor?

P.S. I'm using eclipse 4.2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the way (thanks guys in irc)

```
// ITextEditor editor;
((StyledText)editor.getAdapter(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.class)).addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("key released");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("key pressed ");
    }
});
```