# How to get notified every time an Editor is modified?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a plugin that needs to be notified as changes happen to open files in an Editor.  This needs to happen in real time (similar to how syntax checking is done currently).

[ResourceChangeEvents](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResourceChangeEvent.html) works when I only need to get notified when a file is saved.

[IPropertyChangeListener](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/util/IPropertyChangeListener.html) will tell me when a editor is marked as *dirty*.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618984/how-to-add-keydown-up-event-listener-on-eclipse-rcp-editor-view) question is similar, but is more geared to getting events on a single editor instance and won't scale well for *all* editors.

What about keypress notifications in an editor?  I'm a little surprised they don't cause PropertyChange events.  How can I get such notifications for all editors?

Answer (score 1):

You always have to deal with one text editor at a time.  You would create an *org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener* and start listening to the editor on *partActivated* and stop listening to the editor on *partDeactivated*.

Also, I think you probably want to use *org.eclipse.jface.text.IDocumentListener* to listen to changes in the ITextEditor (instead of targetting the low level widget itself).